# Problem with classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I wrote the following class in javascript

```
function main() 
{
  this.area ;
  this.$= function(target)
  {
    if(target == undefined)
    {
      this.area = document;
    }
    else
    {  
      this.area = document.getElementById(target);
      if( this.area == null )
      {
        this.area = document.getElementsByTagName(target);
        if( this.area[0] == null )
        alert("Error value "+target+" passed to $() is no an id or name");//code to create variable
      }
    }
  }
  this.display = function(value)
    {
      if(this.area == undefined)
      alert("Error in display() method...target not selectedddd");
      else area.innerHTML = value;
    }
}
    and i always get the error message I given as alert. Why area is always null?
```

If I refer to area without using the `this` keyword will it work. Is there any way to nest classes in javascript like

```
function()
{
  this.a;
  function()
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: a= new main() ;$('divId')/* will select element having id /name = divId*/a.display('Hello world') will write Hello world inside that element.....That is what I  need to achieve

Comment: Why do you call your own function `$`? People usually expect it to be used for frameworks like jQuery, Prototype, ...

Comment: Those statements like `this.a;` and `this.area;` make no sense.

Comment: You mean this keyword is not needed to define class variables?

Comment: @user822982: You can't define class variables by just accessing them like `this.area;`, you have to assign a value to them like `this.area = null;`. Just accessing them doesn't accomplish anything, so you can remove that statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is that `this` refers to the inner function scope, not the outer function scope you call a "class".

Try something like this instead:

```
function MyClass() {
    // This is the constructor.
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    method: function() {
    },

    foo: function() {
    }
};

var instance = new MyClasss();
instance.method();
```

Comment: No, that is not correct. When you call a method, `this` refers to the object, not the function scope.

Comment: Is it necessary to create the constructor first?...What is the use of prototype here?..I changed my code as you suggested ...But still the problem remains

Comment: @Guffa: That depends on the call. `this` can be changed, and methods can be called "directly" (e.g. method()) which leads to having `this` either as `window` or `undefined` (as in ES Strict). I'm not really sure what's the case with the OP's code as I don't understand what he is even trying to achieve, but judging by his words "If I refer to area without using the this keyword will it work." it sounds like a scope issue to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @user822982 Yes you need a constructor function for anything you wish to instantiate.

Comment: If the method is called with a different context, then the code that you suggested won't work either. Besides, there is no problem with the scope in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the class, and I don't get the error message.

Usage:

```
var m = new main();
m.$('x');
m.display('Replaced');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ksNSG/

There is an error in the `display` method, however. You are using `area` instead of `this.area`, but that doesn't cause the error message to be displayed, it just keeps the method from setting the content of the element.

#### Edit:

Regarding your comment to the question; the `$` method doesn't return the object, so you can't chain it after the constructor like `var m = new main().$('x');`, you have to call the `$` method after creating the object.

You would have to add a `return this;` last in the `$` method in order to chain the calls that way.

Comment: It is working there ..but when I run it on page it is not working and ahows that area is null ...why is it happening?

Comment: @user822982: One possibility that I see is that you have accidentally redefined `undefined`. As it's not a constant, you can actally change it like any other variable, for example: `undefined = document;`. You should rather check the type of the variable instead of using the `undefined` variable in your code: `if(typeof target == 'undefined')`.